# Javascript Object Hierarchy Simplification

Tags: javascript, json

I have a flat JSON array similar to this:

```
var flatObj = 
[
    { id : "1", parentid : "0", name : "obj 1" },
    { id : "2", parentid : "1", name : "obj 2" },
    { id : "3", parentid : "2", name : "obj 3" },
    { id : "4", parentid : "3", name : "obj 4" },
    { id : "5", parentid : "4", name : "obj 5" },
    { id : "6", parentid : "5", name : "obj 6" },
    { id : "7", parentid : "1", name : "obj 7" },
    { id : "8", parentid : "1", name : "obj 8" },
    { id : "9", parentid : "1", name : "obj 9" }
];
```

I want to display a hierarchy of this by passing an id and get a hierarchy based on that id via the parent ids with a simple function. Not too sure if it matters if I already know how deep it will go but in my case I know the hierarchy stops at 5 levels deep. However, I created a function to do this but its a ton of code?  I want to slim it down possibly use a recursive method?  Here is my function.

```
function getItems(id){

    if(!id){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "";
        id = document.getElementById("hvitems").value;
    }

    for(a=0;a<flatObj.length;a++){

        var object_a = flatObj[a];
        var object_id_a = object_a.id;

        if(object_id_a == id){

            var object_name_a = object_a.name;

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "(" + object_id_a + ") " + object_name_a + "<br>";

            // look for parentid's that match the id
            for(b=0;b<flatObj.length;b++){

                var object_b = flatObj[b];
                var object_id_b = object_b.id;
                var object_pid_b = object_b.parentid;

                if(object_pid_b == object_id_a){

                    var object_name_b = object_b.name;

                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " - (" + object_id_b + ") " + object_name_b + "<br>";

                    // look for parentid's that match the id
                    for(c=0;c<flatObj.length;c++){

                        var object_c = flatObj[c];
                        var object_id_c = object_c.id;
                        var object_pid_c = object_c.parentid;

                        if(object_pid_c == object_id_b){

                            var object_name_c = object_c.name;

                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " -- (" + object_id_c + ") " + object_name_c + "<br>";

                            // look for parentid's that match the id
                            for(d=0;d<flatObj.length;d++){

                                var object_d = flatObj[d];
                                var object_id_d = object_d.id;
                                var object_pid_d = object_d.parentid;

                                if(object_pid_d == object_id_c){

                                    var object_name_d = object_d.name;

                                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " --- (" + object_id_d + ") " + object_name_d + "<br>";

                                    // look for parentid's that match the id
                                    for(e=0;e<flatObj.length;e++){

                                        var object_e = flatObj[e];
                                        var object_id_e = object_e.id;
                                        var object_pid_e = object_e.parentid;

                                        if(object_pid_e == object_id_d){

                                            var object_name_e = object_e.name;

                                            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " ---- (" + object_id_e + ") " + object_name_e + "<br>";

                                            // get all ids of the parentid

                                        }

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}

getItems(1);
// or getItems(3); ...
```

I am displaying it via a div:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

this works great but it seems I need some understanding on recursion or a faster way to do it...

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rn6vuq6h/)

Comment: To learn how I could reduce the amount of code and simplify the function  to do this. I see a lot of repetitive for loops and was wondering if there is a better way to code it?

Comment: You implement recursion, and you know it already. Do you want someone to teach you how to develop recursions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have N nested loops. That's why we have [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).

The algorithm will be the following:

- For index `id`

  - Find the item with this `id` and output information
  - Find all items with `parentid` equal to `id` and repeat these steps using their `id`

As simple as that:

```
function getItems(id, indent) { // for index `id`
    var current = flatObj.filter(function(x) { // find the item... 
        return (x.id == id); // ... with this id
    })[0];

    // and output information
    document.body.innerHTML += indent + " (" + current.id + ") " + current.name + "<br>"; 

    // find all items ...
    flatObj.forEach(function(x) {        
        if (x.parentid == id) { // ...with parentid equal to id
            getItems(x.id, indent + '-'); // and repeat these steps using their ids
        }
    });
}

getItems(id, '');
```

`indent` is just a string which is empty in the beginning, and is increased by one `-` on every recursive call, so that it looks like you need.

Here is the working [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rtup6s2n/1/).

Note that this algorithm supposes that it is a **tree** and input parameters are valid. It doesn't check for loops, or existence of parent node with such id. You may implement it, if you need.

Comment: aaaah, I see now... I like the forEach function call back.  And I completely agree I definitely needed to use recursion I did not want to go about doing it the way I was doing it. Thanks!!!!